# Need help to install c++ grpc on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, grpc

I tried to install grpc by executing the following

```
git clone -b $(curl -L http://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
cd grpc
git submodule update --init
make
```

But when I run make, I get the message "#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is"

But, I have the latest protoc installed ...

```
/usr/bin/protoc --version
libprotoc 3.2.0
```

Comment: It would help if you would show the full error, especially telling which file is causing an issue.

Comment: I have published a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/plusangel/grpc-cplusplus-ubuntu18) that you can use in Ubuntu Bionic - it might help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to my own question ...
The issue gets resolved when I remove the third party protobuf files before running install.

`rm -rf third_party/protobuf`

I am not exactly sure why this works though ...